# 子テーブルの積集合をとりたい

Tags: mysql, sql

１対多の親子関係にあるテーブルがあって
親を任意条件で検索して子レコードの特定のカラムで積集合(全てに含まれる値)をとりたいのですが
MySQL でどう書けばいいんでしょうか

例えば

children レコードが

```
FK|VAL
--+---
1 | a
1 | b
1 | c
2 | b
2 | c
2 | d
3 | c
3 | d
3 | e
```

つまり

```
parents 1 が children [a,b,c] を持つ
parents 2 が children [b,c,d] を持つ
parents 3 が children [c,d,e] を持つ
```

ような状態で
親の検索結果が1,2,3だったら [abc][bcd][cde] 全てに含まれる [c] のみ
親が 1,2 だったら [abc][bcd] に含まれる [b,c]
という結果になるようにしたいです

さらに親の検索結果が０件だった場合と、親の検索結果は存在するけど積をとった結果０件になった場合も区別したいので
[] と [NULL] を返すか、別カラムにフラグのようなものをつけて返したいです

2 つの積集合なら INNER JOIN をとればいいんですが
親の検索結果が何個になるかわからないのでどう書けばいいのでしょうか

クエリを分けてフレームワーク側で積を取るしかないでしょうか

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with parent_ids as (
  select 1
  union all
  select 2
  union all
  select 3
), children as (
  select 1 as fk, 'a' as val
  union all
  select 1, 'b'
  union all
  select 1, 'c'
  union all
  select 2, 'b'  
  union all
  select 2, 'c'
  union all
  select 2, 'd'
  union all
  select 3, 'c'
  union all
  select 3, 'd'
  union all
  select 3, 'e'
)
select children.val, count(*) as cnt from children where children.fk IN (select * from parent_ids)
group by children.val
having cnt = (select count(*) from parent_ids);
```

上記を実行すると、

```
val | cnt
---------
  c |   3
```

が取得できます。

親が 0 件かどうか、は、別クエリで実行した方が、結果シンプルになるのではないか、と思っています。(もしくはさらに CTE を発展させるか)

Comment: val 側を主体で集計してカウントが親レコードと同じものを取得するんですね。積集合に囚われすぎていたので発想に至りませんでした。大変勉強になります。